# Idiom and grammar

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

> The day was like any other day but the different thing it was me.

Do you know any idiom for this sentence?

And is this sentence right?

How can I make it better?

Comment: @killingTime  Thanks a lot

Comment: The text ***the different thing it was me*** isn't remotely valid English. What exactly are you trying to say here? That *for other people*, there was nothing unusual about that day, but *for me personally*, it was [to become?] in some way a particularly "notable, significant, special" day?

Comment: Yes, I want to say " on that day for other people there was nothing unusual but for me was" but   I want to say this sentence in a nutshell

Comment: Maybe someone else can think of a succinct way to say *exactly* all that, but personally I think you're trying to cram to many different elements into a single sentence. Semantically, there's no point in explicitly bringing in *other people*, when all that really matters is ***you** weren't expecting anything unusual* (before the day started, and presumably for some time ***into*** the day, until something unusual happened). Note that it's extremely common in English to say/write ***The day started out like any other, BUT** [then something happened]* (no need to explicitly say ***for me***).

Comment: Ok Thanks so much

Comment: @killingtime  sorry to be bothering you again  "If that day was like any other day there wouldn't have been any problem but it wasn't, because of competition which was about woodcraft and was going to be held in my school."  Finally, This sentence is right?

Comment: Now I'm getting confused! Surely if you *knew* there was going to be a "competition about woodcraft", you would already have known it *wasn't* going to be an "ordinary day". I don't want to get too bogged down in "proofreading" your attempts here, but I will just say your most recent version above is one of those relatively uncommon contexts where Past **Perfect** is better for talking about an "unreal / hypothetical" situation in the past: *If that day **had been** like any other day there wouldn't have been any problem...* And your "because" clause needs ***the*** before ***competition***.

Comment: @fumblefingers  Yes, you're right Thank you for helping me improve